# why is PUT not being recognized in controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, crud

I am trying to update a customers feedback post, the POST & DELETE work but I have been stuck on the PUT for a couple of days. any help will be great. thanks

Factory

```
app.factory('Post', function ($resource) {

return $resource('/api/apiPost/:id',
{ id: '@id' },
{ 'save': { method: 'POST' } },
{ 'update': { method: 'PUT' } },
{ 'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: false } });
```

});

CONTROLLER

```
$scope.updatePost = function (post) {
    //alert("WORKS");
    Post.update({ id: post.PostId }, $scope.post, function () {
        $scope.postArray.push(post);
        $scope.post = {
            Title: '',
            Body: ''
        };
    }, function () { });


}
```

ADAPTER

```
 public Post PutNewPost(int id, Post newPost)
    {

        Post post = new Post();
        post.PostId = newPost.PostId;
        post.Title = newPost.Title;
        post.Body = newPost.Body;
        post.Hidden = newPost.Hidden;

        db.Posts.Add(post);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return db.Posts.FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

API CONTROLLER

```
// PUT api/<controller>/5
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public IHttpActionResult Put(int id, [FromBody]Post newPost)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        return Ok(_adapter.PutNewPost(id, newPost));
    }
```

ERROR MESSAGE

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at h.$scope.updatePost (https://localhost:44301/MyScripts/AjaxPostController.js:40:14)
at https://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.min.js:169:382
at https://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.min.js:186:390
at h.$eval (https://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.min.js:108:40)
at h.$apply (https://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.min.js:108:318)
at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (https://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.min.js:186:372)
at HTMLInputElement.o.event.dispatch (https://localhost:44301/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js:3:6055)
at HTMLInputElement.r.handle (https://localhost:44301/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js:3:2830)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your method arguments for $resource are mistaken. Return all your custom methods in 1 object like this:

```
app.factory('Post', function ($resource) {

return $resource('/api/apiPost/:id',
    { id: '@id' },
    { 
        'save': { method: 'POST' },
        'update': { method: 'PUT' },
        'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: false }
    }
);
```